# How to Check Device Boot Mode (UEFI or Legacy)?

Tags: powershell

How can I use Powershell to determine if a device is running in UEFI or Legacy boot mode and return a simple string that says "UEFI" or "Legacy"?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://wintech.sgal.info/2016/12/easy-way-to-determine-uefi-or-legacy.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below is for elevated, there might be ways to get it non-elevated, but you didn't specify if that was a requirement so here it is.

Run this in an elevated PowerShell:

```
$BootMode = bcdedit | Select-String "path.*efi"
if ($null -eq $BootMode) {
    # I think non-uefi is \Windows\System32\winload.exe
    $BootMode = "Legacy"
}else {
    # UEFI is: 
    #path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
    #path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
    $BootMode = "UEFI"
}

Write-Host "Computer is running in $BootMode boot mode."
```

If it has `.efi` in the path, its UEFI mode. If it shows `.exe`, it's the legacy boot if my memory serves me right.

Answer (score 0):

Run that on Powershell without elevation:

```
$env:firmware_type
```

Returns "UEFI" or "Legacy"